# why there are errors when i install solc compiler with npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, solidity

with the latest version of npm but i cant install compiler successfully.

```js
ash@ubuntu:~/inbox$ node -v
v8.11.1
ash@ubuntu:~/inbox$ npm -v
5.8.0
ash@ubuntu:~/inbox$ sudo npm install --save solc
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ash/inbox/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ash/inbox/package.json'
npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.14 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN inbox No description
npm WARN inbox No repository field.
npm WARN inbox No README data
npm WARN inbox No license field.

+ solc@0.4.21
updated 1 package in 5.593s
ash@ubuntu:~/inbox$
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsV0B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to install into a project directory which will try to update the project's `package.json` file to add the dependency. The install still worked. You will find it under `node_modules/solc`.

The better approach is to install it globally:

```
npm install -g solc
```